# how do i pass parameters into function in vba

Tags: vba, parameter-passing

As the title, I wrote a function in VBA but the parameter didn't pass into the function.
This's my code:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e5DPn.png)

thanks you so much

```
    Function Solar_altitude_angle() As Single
    'Declare
Dim n As Integer
Dim Longtitude As Single
Dim Latitude As Single
Dim Altitude As Single
Dim LSM As Integer
Dim LST As Single
Dim ET As Single
Dim H As Single
Dim AST As Single
Dim i_SolarDeclination As Single
Dim s_Gama As Single

    'Equation time

n = DateDiff("d", "01/01/2021", ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("D62"))
Longtitude = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("E61")
Latitude = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("B61")
Altitude = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("G61")
LSM = 105 'oE Greenwich
LST = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("H62")

i_SolarDeclination = 23.45 * Sin((n + 284) / 365 * 2 * 3.14159)

s_Gama = ((n - 1) / 365) * 2 * 3.14159
ET = 2.2918 * (0.0075 _
            + 0.1868 * Cos(s_Gama) _
            - 3.2077 * Sin(s_Gama) _
            - 1.4615 * Cos(2 * s_Gama) _
            - 4.089 * Sin(2 * s_Gama))
   
AST = LST * 24 + ET / 60 + (Longtitude - LSM) / 15

H = 15 * (AST - 12)

Solar_altitude_angle = (Application.Asin(Cos(Longtitude) * Cos(i_SolarDeclination) * Cos(H) + _
                        Sin(Longtitude) * Sin(i_SolarDeclination))) * 180 / 3.1412
                        
End Function
```

as the picture above, in the watches window show variables invalid.

Comment: @KostasK. thank you, here the code

Comment: The function doesn't accept any arguments `Solar_altitude_angle()`. You need to declare them between the brackets `()`.

Comment: For example `Solar_altitude_angle(ByVal someValue as Long, ByVal anotherValue as String, [...]) As Single`.

Comment: See also [MS VBA reference: Function statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/function-statement) and [Understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/understanding-named-arguments-and-optional-arguments) @iatnart

Comment: it don't work, how do i can fix it?

Comment: If you think about it for a second, ... *it don't work,* alone, without any clarifying description of what you actually did, that now doesn't work, is rather useless. So, please **edit your question and show what exactly you tried**, and what exactly you mean with *it don't work,*

Comment: Looking closer at your question post, what parameter(s) are you talking about when you say *"but the parameter didn't pass into the function"*? What parameters would you like to pass into the function?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing you want to pass the ranges from `Room_Load` to your function.
Without any thought to what the parameter types should be except to get it working - I had to change `n` from a single to a date so `DateDiff` could calculate.

Each parameter to be passed is used in the function name.

```
Public Function Solar_altitude_angle(n As Date, Longtitude As Single, Latitude As Single, _
                                     Altitude As Single, LST As Single) As Single

    Dim n1 As Integer
    n1 = DateDiff("d", DateSerial(Year(Date), 1, 1), n)
    
    Dim LSM As Integer
    LSM = 105

    Dim i_SolarDeclination As Single
    i_SolarDeclination = 23.45 * Sin((n + 284) / 365 * 2 * 3.14159)
    
    Dim s_Gama As Single
    s_Gama = ((n - 1) / 365) * 2 * 3.14159
    
    Dim ET As Single
    ET = 2.2918 * (0.0075 _
                + 0.1868 * Cos(s_Gama) _
                - 3.2077 * Sin(s_Gama) _
                - 1.4615 * Cos(2 * s_Gama) _
                - 4.089 * Sin(2 * s_Gama))
       
    Dim AST As Single
    AST = LST * 24 + ET / 60 + (Longtitude - LSM) / 15
    
    Dim H As Single
    H = 15 * (AST - 12)
    
    Solar_altitude_angle = (Application.Asin(Cos(Longtitude) * Cos(i_SolarDeclination) * Cos(H) + _
                            Sin(Longtitude) * Sin(i_SolarDeclination))) * 180 / 3.1412

End Function
```

This can then be called from VBA using something like:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim MyResult As Single
    MyResult = Solar_altitude_angle(ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("D62"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("E61"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("B61"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("G61"), _
                                    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Room_Load").Range("H62"))
                                

End Sub
```

or as a worksheet function:

```
=Solar_altitude_angle(Room_Load!D62,Room_Load!E61, Room_Load!B61, Room_Load!G61, Room_Load!H62)
```

or

```
=Solar_altitude_angle(D62,E61, B61,G61, H62)
```

Comment: Thank you, so now I have a trouble. I make a function, parameters passed function ok. But every variables I declare in function body is always return values 0 with numeric type or empty with String type. However, I checked in Immediate window the code return correct result. What' wrong? and how to fix it?

Comment: What are the variables you're declaring in the body?  The ones you pass as a function parameter shouldn't be declared in the body - they're declared in the function name.